# What are the odds that one value picked from a uniform distribution is greater than any other?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given the [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) $U(a,b)$ and any 2 values $u_1,u_2$ picked from $U$, what are the odds that $u_1 > u_2$?

Comment: You are sampling a random variable $(X,Y)$ from the square $[a,b]^2$. The probability that $X>Y$ is the integral of the joint density of $(X,Y)$ over the portion of the square defined by $x>y$. Can you continue?

Comment: Use symmetry and the fact that equality has probability $0$.

Comment: My intuition says it is $\frac{1}{2}$, but I unfortunately know little about probability, and I prefer knowing things as fact than simply going off of intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By symmetry, the probability that $u_1\gt u_2$ is equal to the probability that $u_2\gt u_1$. Since the distribution is continuous, $u_1\ne u_2$. Therefore, the probability that $u_1\gt u_2=\frac{1}{2}$.